# Temporal: Using time related functions in activity implementation

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

The documentation says

> Only use Workflow.currentTimeMillis() to get the current time inside a
> Workflow.

Does it apply only to workflows or activities as well? Can I use `System.currentTimeMillis()` in activity implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation constraints mentioned in [docs](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/java-implementing-workflows/#workflow-implementation-constraints) applies to workflows and not the activities. `System.currentTimeMillis()` can be used in an activity implementation. [OP here](https://community.temporal.io/t/getting-current-time-in-an-activity/1845).